# Drawing really long text on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Currently I have `UITableViewCell's` that hold sometimes really long text (up to 50,000 pixels in height after drawing). However the [UITableView delegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) says that cells shouldn't be higher than 2009 pixels in height (any ideas why?).

It's only the first section in my table view that has the really long cell, so instead of using a cell for the first section, I thought I'd create a `UIScrollView`, put a `UITextView` as the first "cell" and add it to the `scrollView`, and then add the `tableView` to the scroll view as well (under the `textView`). However, having a 50,000 px high `UITextView` is causing huge memory problems.

What are my options? I know I could use a `UITextView` that scrolls, but to have a scrollable `UITextView` with a `tableView` just causes complicated scrolling behavior. I want to mimic the scrolling of a tableView.

I didn't know it would be an issue to have a 50,000 px high view in a `UIScrollView`. I thought that's what `UIScrollView's` are for? Do I have any alternatives?

Comment: Yes which is why I'm asking for alternatives..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would seriously question the UI design where you must render text that large as part of a table cell. The best option would be to put a reasonably-sized summary in a cell with `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`, build a separate view for the long text, and let the user navigate to that view by clicking the disclosure indicator.

As a side note, you *could* also put a scroll view inside the initial table cell (not all cells must be of the same type; you can make one with a scroll view in it, and use it for the cell at index zero). It's not going to be as usable as the regular cell with a disclosure indicator, though.

Comment: Well the using of cells is just a layout issue. The first section is the blog post, and the other sections are comments. The blog post can sometimes be very long. They previous view was a cell with a disclosure indicator, and now they are in the actual detail view. Generally speaking, how would I present such long text?

Comment: @mohabitar You can use a view with multiple `UITextView` elements to display parts of your text (see [this blog post](http://blog.tofodo.com/2009/03/iphone-sdk-doesnt-like-long-texts.html) for details). Alternatively, you could use the same trick with `UITableView`: cut off the text of the first row, and put a "show more" label into the second row. When clicked, add a second cell with the next portion of the text (now you have parts of the text in cells 1 and 2, and "more" label in cell 3). As the user clicks "show more", add more cells with text portions of the post dynamically.